# How to calculate multiplication value inside the while loop in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one while loop which displays data from the database.  Now I want multiply two values in one row and display the result in the same row, the same way multiply the values and display the result in every row.  I am not getting the result.  Can anyone help me?  I am new to PHP.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td class='alt'>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['item'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
   $ss=$row['amount'];
   echo '<td >'.'<input type="checkbox"  name="status" value="" >'.'</td>';
   echo '<td >'.'<input type="text" name="qty">'.'</td>';
   echo "<td>" . $rr1 . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From Where you are getting `$rr1`??

You can have

`echo "<td>" . $row['item'] * $row['amount'] . "</td>";`

Hope this is what you want...

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
printf('amount is %d',$row['item'] * $row['amount']);
```

[reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: I assume everything as an integer. you can write`'%f'` too

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td class='alt'>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['item'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" .($row['item'] * $row['amount']). "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the query as

```
$result= mysql_query("Select id, item, amount, (item * amount)  total
 from table_name");
```

then in while loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td >" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['item'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" .($row['total']  "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
     }
```